# Unable to create Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a function which should be called every time when `DELETE` happens. However, I get error messages when I try to save it. This is how it looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_layers_before_del () RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
DECLARE
    table_name text := (SELECT concat ('layer_', OLD.id::text, '_')); 
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE '
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' CASCADE
    '
END;
$$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

Navicat says that there is a syntax error and points to the line with `END;` code. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: try deleting the semicolor after END

Comment: If I delete it, I get another error message

Comment: Now it says that `INTO or USING or ;` is missing

Comment: add semicolon after CASCADE

Comment: Oh, it works. I added it right after the last single quote. Thank you, sir!